# Coalesce equivalent in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql

I need to know what the PostgreSQL `coalesce()` equivalent is in Linq. I read that it was the `??` operator [(source)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx), but that doesn't seem to work.

I have a string query that will be run in linq. The where clause looks like so:

```
WHERE
ToLower((hnHN.value ?? String.Empty) + ' ' + (hnSN.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' + (hnSS.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' 
        + (hnAN.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' +  (hnC.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' + (hnS.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' 
        + (hnZ.value ?? String.Empty) + ' ' +  (hnZ4.value ?? String.Empty) ) LIKE + ToLower('%test%')
```

When I run the string with this where clause as a linq query I get the following error:

`The query syntax is not valid. Near term '?', line 26, column 22.`

Ideas?

**EDIT** To clear up confusion, we are replicating a linq query through strings. When the method is finished, it will return a string that we run as a linq query. The code:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format(@"ToLower((hnHN.value ?? String.Empty) + ' ' + (hnSN.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' + (hnSS.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' 
        + (hnAN.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' +  (hnC.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' + (hnS.value ?? String.Empty)  + ' ' + (hnZ.value ?? String.Empty)  +
        ' ' +  (hnZ4.value ?? String.Empty) ) LIKE + ToLower('%{1}%') AND", name, ((string)val).Trim()));
```

Comment: Well you've got capital `WHERE` which isn't valid C# to start with, and what is `ToLower` doing? And what about the `LIKE` part? Basically, this doesn't look like C# at the moment...

Comment: And what's the story with the LIKE? Don't you need a space around it?

Comment: It is a bit confusing, but we are creating a sting that will be used as a linq query. The Where is in a `StringBuilder.append("WHERE")` line. That is what it would look like when run as a query. 

The `toLower()` code is to ensure that we do not get comparison issues when comparing "TEST" to "test"

Comment: You haven't given us *nearly* enough context here. This code clearly isn't being compiled as straight C#, and we don't know how it *is* being handled. The `??` operator is part of C#, the language... if whatever you're using to process your query isn't "the C# compiler" then it's basically irrelevant.

Comment: I added an edit to show the line. The method is pretty long, but we are appending strings. We then run this through linq. Hopefully that is enough info. I think I found a solution using `CASE` statements anyways. Hopefully that will work

Comment: What do you mean by "run it through linq"? LINQ executes expression trees, how are you getting an expression tree from that?

Comment: I won't want to jump the gun but certainly there is a more appropriate and maintainable (and testable!) way to generate an expression to be executed against your Postgres database, whether it's via LINQ or not. Maybe if you described your goal and/or what problem you're trying to solve we can guide you towards the right path.

Comment: are you sure you do not need to escape your question marks? please edit your question to highlight line 26 : column 22

Comment: I ended up using case statements. Thanks for the help anyways! And i agree that the way we do it is less than ideal, but we dont have time to remake the whole class unfortunately